# Loading a flexible fact table SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have the following fact table : PlaceId, DateId, StatisticId, StatisticValue.
And I have a dimension with the statistics Ids and its names as the following : StatisticId, StatisticName.

I want to load the fact table with Data with 2 statistics. With this architecture, each row of my data will be represented with 2 rows in my fact table.

The Data has the following attributes : Place,Date,Stat1_Value, Stat2_Value.

How to load my fact table with Ids of these measures and its corresponding Values.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SSIS to move your data into a holding table that has the same columns as your data.   Then call a stored procedure that uses SQL to populate your fact table, using UNION to get all the Stat1_Values, and then all the Stat2_Values.